# Closing auto focus to jquery dialog when it is opened

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

[This is my site](http://www.bunch-it.com) and I have a problem on my popup bubbles. These are actually jquery dialogs. When you scroll down the page to the video, they force you scroll up when they are poped up. How could I close this auto focus feature of these dialogs?

Comment: I don't see the popup bubbles on your site.  What do you need to do to make them appear?

Comment: I cannot solve the problem so I changes my implementation :(

Answer (score 0):

not sure how active you still are on the site, but the issue is because the links you use to open the dialog have a hash mark as the href:

```
<a href="#">open dialog</a>
```

This hash in an anchor indicates a hash link. Without an id, it uses the window object and scrolls back to the top of the page.

To prevent, use:

```
<a href="javascript: void(0);">open dialog</a>
```